# Cannot change permissions recursively using `-R` on macOS after reinstallation

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, macos-sierra

I have been using macOS for more than 2 years now, and after a fresh reinstall I cannot do

```
sh-3.2# sudo chmod 777 -R .
chmod: -R: No such file or directory
```

I can change permissions on my folder not recursively, that means the error appears when I am using the `-R` option.

Is there a way to fix this in my computer? maybe installing another unix shell ?

Comment: firstly permission 777 is not a good option at all in any scenario, and where is folder name?

Comment: @TusharSharma that was just an example, I cannot apply it at `~/.ssh` folder and I am actually trying to change it to 600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Access mask should be placed after options

Comment: weird, but thanks, I did it the other way on ubuntu installations and this was not a problem, probably it has to be with the macOS installed shell, thanks

Comment: Just tried. Works fine for me. Didn't you forget dot on the end of the line? But I use bash

Comment: @WhGandalf It's not the shell, it's due to different versions of the `chmod` utility. Traditional unix syntax is that command options (things that start with `-`) come before a command's positional parameters.Some utilities (including most of the GNU utilities that linuxes use) relax this and allow options anywhere among the positional parameters.